# How to scroll to the element using scrollBehavior and hash in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

I have page with a lot of components and I like to scroll to the point during opening the page.
In `mounted` I have method which is pushing hash to the routes.
the page:

```html
<template>
<section>
   <ComponentA />
   <ComponentB />
   <ComponentC />
   <div id="#scrollHere">
       <ComponentD />
   </div>
   <ComponentE />
   <ComponentF />
</section>
</template>
<script>
...
mounted() {
        this.$router.push({name: 'pageName', hash: '#scrollHere'});
    }
</script>
```

**router.js**

```js
const router = new VueRouter({
  routes,
  mode: "history",
  scrollBehavior(to) {
    if (to.hash) {
      return {
        selector: to.hash
      };
    }
  }
});
```

During opening the page nothing happen. Do you have any advices?

***EDIT***
I resolved the issue. 
1. As said *@Delena Malan* (thanks!), removal `#` from `div id="#scrollHere"` was necessary.
2. I set Promise with timeOut in scrollBehaviour. The problem was in scrollBehavior my div didn't exist, so it was imposibble to scroll.

**router.js**

```
const scrollBehavior = to => {
  if (to.hash) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        resolve({ selector: to.hash });
      }, 1000);
    });
  }
};
```

Comment: Aren't you redirecting infinitely? Because every time the component is mounted, you push another route?

Comment: To be honest nothing happen. I'm just trying to scroll to the element during opening the page using native scrollBehavior. When I'm using regular window.scrollTo my page is not fully mounted in the DOM and scroll dosen't go to the correct position.

Comment: Also, you should probably remove the `#` from `<div id="#scrollHere">`.

Comment: Thank you! I removed # from id and hash is correctly added to URL. URL looks like something.com/my-subpage#scrollHere and suddenly #scrollHere is removing. Do you have any ideas why? I use history mode.

Comment: I think the `hash` parameter might cause weird behaviours because it's actually meant to be used with hash mode. I think you can try using a `query` value (or if that doesn't work a `param`) for your routing. E.g. ` this.$router.push({name: 'pageName', query: { hash: '#scrollHere' } });` and in your router: `if (to.query.hash) {` etc.

Comment: It's werid. Everything is removing from URL, dosen't matter query or hash. Param/params dosen't trigger scrollBehavior.

Comment: Maybe create a reproducible example on Codepen or similar platform, then someone can help you.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that you need in order to scroll top after each route change is to add this in router file

```
scrollBehavior(to, from, savedPosition){
  return{ left: 0, top: 0}
}
```

in case you want to go back and visit your last browser position you can do this:

```
scrollBehavior(to, from, savedPosition){
  if(savedPosition){
    return savedPosition
  }
  return{ left: 0, top: 0}
}
```